# MYSQL Sub Query with two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying to get a sub query to work but I'm thinking it needs to be join instead but I'm new to databases and having a hard time wrapping my head around just how it works.

I need to collect a rows from userprofile based on three columns in connect, what I have that doesn't work is this.

```
SELECT * FROM userprofile WHERE user_id IN 
(SELECT connect.user_id, connect.connect_to_id FROM connect WHERE 
(user_id = '1' OR connect_to_id = '1') AND is_connected = '1' );
```

Because the second SELECT has two columns listed it errors with

```
#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Having just one column listed in the second join doesn't return all entries, only the ones that the first test meets.

Does this have to be done with JOIN and if so how? Every join that I try just results in all entries from the userprofile table being returned.

Thanks for your help.

*UPDATE

I have two queries working now.

```
SELECT u.* FROM userprofile u 
JOIN connect c ON (u.user_id = c.user_id OR u.user_id = c.connect_to_id) WHERE
    ((c.user_id = '1' OR c.connect_to_id = '1') AND c.is_connected = '1') AND u.user_id != '1'
GROUP BY u.id;
```

And

```
SELECT u.* FROM userprofile u WHERE u.user_id IN 
(SELECT connect.user_id FROM connect WHERE connect.connect_to_id = '1' AND connect.is_connected = '1'
UNION ALL
SELECT connect.connect_to_id FROM connect WHERE connect.user_id = '1' AND connect.is_connected = '1')
```

Over 10000 calls using microtime I have the second using the Sub Query being a tad faster.

```
Join Query:4.6199560165405
Sub Query:4.0528790950775
```

I then decided to do a test to see why and discovered that the GROUP BY command is slowing down the JOIN considerably. So with the GROUP BY removed I get these numbers.

```
Join Query:2.6410460472107
Sub Query:4.1510140895844
```

As it turns out I don't really need the GROUP BY as I'm checking that u.user_id != '1' and this stops the same problem I was having.

So the question, is using GROUP BY frowned on?

Comment: What is the logic that you want?  You have a query that clearly doesn't work.  Sample data and desired results are a big help.

Comment: I want all the found rows from userprofile if user_id or connect_to_id in connect table are true and is_connected is true. The structure of userprofile really doesn't make a difference I don't think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done either via a `join` or a sub-query. Typically with MySQL joins are more efficient because in many cases MySQL is unable to use indexes with sub-queries. So, in your case the query with a join would be:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM
    userprofile u
    JOIN connect c ON (u.user_id = c.user_id OR u.user_id = c.connect_to_id)
WHERE
    (c.user_id = '1' OR c.connect_to_id = '1') AND
    c.is_connected = '1'
```

Comment: I think that I see what I was missing with JOIN. So the u.user_id in userprofile gets set to the value that is returned after the WHERE?

Comment: And I assume that you believe this to be the better solution over the one below from Pastor because of tolerance to errors or is there a speed increase as well?

Comment: This works great. They syntax of sql just doesn't fall into place with me at the moment. For instance ON, I'm assuming that is saying that ON this parameter map it this way?

The WHERE is obvious and I have added a GROUP BY that also is making sense to me. 

And thanks for the help @Unix One

Comment: @PaulNeale to explain the join query: `ON` clause specifies the constraints of the join; in this case it contains the join constraint as exactly specified by you - `u.user_id` equal to `c.user_id` `OR` the `c.connect_to_id`. The `WHERE` clause is where I put the constraint for specific rows you'd like to return. To answer the speed question, you should measure, but rule of thumb is MySQL likes joins better. Also, you could try running `explain` on each of those queries to see what indexes get used with each.

Comment: Thanks for answering those questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are with two problems. One of them is the two colmumns thing. The other one is a cartesian product.

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM userprofile up
 WHERE up.user_id IN (SELECT connect.user_id
            FROM connect 
               WHERE connect.connect_to_id = '1'
               UNION ALL
              SELECT connect.connect_to_id 
            FROM connect 
               WHERE connect.user_id = '1') 
   AND is_connected = '1' ;
```

Comment: I was wondering if I could use two subs but didn't understand how to write that. UNION ALL would be what I was missing. 

I will give this a try and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can do what you want using `exists`:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM userprofile u
WHERE user_id IN 
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM connect c
              WHERE '1' IN (c.user_id, c.connect_to_id) AND
                    c.is_connected = '1' AND
                    u.user_id IN (c.user_id, c.connect_to_id)
             );
```

Note:  If the ids are numeric values, then don't use single quotes around the constants.  The mixing of types can confuse the optimizer.

Comment: Interesting thought. I'm going to test the JOIN method first only because I keep reading that it is the best way to go about it. Any discussion on what way might be best for what reason would be great.

Answer (score 0):

@Pastor
I had to do an update to your code as I was getting an error in the is_connected column check

```
SELECT * 
FROM userprofile up
    WHERE up.user_id IN (SELECT connect.user_id
        FROM connect 
            WHERE connect.connect_to_id = '1' AND connect.is_connected = '1'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT connect.connect_to_id 
            FROM connect 
                WHERE connect.user_id = '1' AND connect.is_connected = '1')
```